# The Levi's decomposition in Lie theory and the problem of classification Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, classifying-spaces

It is well-know that: "any finite-dimensional Lie algebra over a field of characteristic zero can be expressed as a semidirect sum of a semi-simple subalgebra and its radical (its maximal solvable ideal). It reduces the task of classifying all Lie algebras to obtaining the classification of semi-simple and of solvable Lie algebras". I am wondering about that "reduction". Let's consider the following simple example: let $L=M\otimes_\phi N$ is a semidirect product of Lie algebras where $M \subseteq L$ and $N\subseteq L$ are commutative Lie subalgebras of $L$ and the Lie structure on $L$ depends on $\phi$. If so, followed by the above claim, $\phi$ does not play any role in the problem of classifying such Lie algebras?

Comment: Is your notation $\otimes_\phi$ a nonstandard notation for a semidirect product $\ltimes$? Relatedly, what exactly is $\phi$?

Comment: If $L$ is the semidirect product of abelian subalgebras, then $L$ is solvable. So we are already in the solvable case.

Comment: Yes, I mean the semidirect product. The $\phi$ is a bilinear map. In the example, $\phi(x,y)=[x,y]$ for $x\in M$ and $y\in N$.

Comment: I agree, if L is the semidirect product of abelian subalgebras, then $L$ is solvable and we are in solvable case. But does it follow that the classifcation of all semidirect product of abelian Lie algebras are known?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Levi decomposition of $L$ is given by
$$
L=\mathfrak{s}\ltimes_{\phi} {\rm rad}(L),
$$
where $\mathfrak{s}$ is a semisimple subalgebra of $L$, and ${\rm rad}(L)$
the maximal solvable ideal of $L$. Suppose now we have classified all semisimple Lie algebras $\mathfrak{s}$, and we would know all solvable ones (which we don't). Then we know all $L$.

So, given a Lie algebra $L$, we need to find its Levi decomposition. There is an algorithm, how to compute it. The map $\phi$ must be a Lie algebra homomorphism $\phi\colon \mathfrak{s}\rightarrow {\rm Der}({\rm rad}(L))$.
Then we know $L$ from this decomposition, because we know $\mathfrak{s}$ and the solvable ideal.

Comment: Do you mean that, we just know all $L$, or we may know all classification up to isomorphism of L? It looks like we must have a suitable "classification" on $\phi$, too.

Comment: Yes, we also need to determine the possible $\phi$'s. But for a given $L$, we can construct the Levi decomposition together with some $\phi$ by an algorithm. Then the problem is reduced to classifying the Levi subalgebras and the solvable radicals.